# How do you get the keys of the innermost object

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have an object:

```
var obj = {
    "level1": {
        "level2": {
            "level3": {
                "k1": "v1",
                "k2": "v2",
                "k3": "v3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be:

```
"k1": "v1",
"k2": "v2",
"k3": "v3"
```

I wrote a function

```
function objRecursive (obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] === "object") {
            objRecursive(obj[key]);
        }
        console.log(key, ": ", obj[key]);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't print the values of the innermost object. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: A potential problem might be that you're calling `eachRecursive` instead of `objRecursive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function innerKeys(o) { 
  return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) { 
    return typeof o[k] === 'object' ? innerKeys(o[k]) : (r[k] = o[k], r) 
  }, {}) 
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr9mgv9g/)

Comment: it does't work on the following type of code
"{"1":{"2":{"Parts":"3761|55.55|1|0"}}}" i just want Parts value